# Remove cross-references to sections from bibliography entries

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

I am using an in-document bibliography i.e.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{R:30}
...
\end{thebibliography}
```

For reasons unknown this results in latex placing an index of section references to each bibitem after each item, the 1,4, and A in the following example.

```
Tolsoty, Leo. War and Peace. New York: Ecco, 2007 1 4 A
```

How can I remove the section references at the end of each bibitem?

Comment: Ah, apparently someone has included a package named hyperref which is causing this behavior.  Is there a way to turn off the section references using the hyperref options?

Comment: Be sure to set `backref=false` among the hyperref setup options (or just omit the `backref` option entirely).

Comment: Glad this worked! I've posted my comment as an answer; please feel free to upvote and/or accept it. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You note in a comment that the `hyperref` package is loaded as well. Be sure to set the option `backref=false` among the hyperref setup options, or just omit any mention of the `backref` option entirely. This should stop the unwanted behavior you describe.